# Enter in curve draw option with a script

Tags: python, scripting, bezier-curves, draw-mode

I need via script to enters into *Edit Mode* (of a bezier curve) and then immediately into [`Draw`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/curves/tools/draw.html) mode.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an [`Operator`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html) which you can name as *Draw Curve Operator*.

```
import bpy

def main(context):
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    bpy.ops.wm.tool_set_by_id(name="builtin.draw")

class DrawCurveOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.draw_curve_operator"
    bl_label = "Draw Curve Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        o = context.active_object
        return o is not None and o.type == 'CURVE'

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}

def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(DrawCurveOperator.bl_idname, text=DrawCurveOperator.bl_label)

# Register and add to the "object" menu (required to also use F3 search "Draw Curve Operator" for quick access)
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(DrawCurveOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(menu_func)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(DrawCurveOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.remove(menu_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Run the script to register the [`Operator`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html). Then in Object mode, select your [`Bezier Curve`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/curves/index.html) and press <kbd>F3</kbd> and search for *Draw Curve* and select it to execute the operator to automatically enter into *Edit Mode* with [`Draw Tool`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/curves/tools/draw.html) active.

[image]

You can also do it quicker by adding your operator to [`Quick Favorites`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/tool_system.html#quick-favorites) by right clicking the *Draw Curve Operator* in the list and selecting *Add to Quick Favorites*.

[image]

Now you can do it as quick as selecting the curve and pressing <kbd>Q</kbd> and selecting your *Draw Curve Operator*.

[image]